# Как вызвать метод класса из view в Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

У меня есть класс рейтинг, мне нужно вызвать метод из класса, который отобразит число во view

Comment: view - это не место для вызовов методов из других классов. Вызовите его в контроллере, и через контроллер передайте значение во view.

Comment: соглашусь с предыдущим оратором, но если почему-то очень надо, то можно передать инстанс класса в массиве даты который вы передаете в view. правда непонятно зачем это может понадобиться